# Modifying an existing paypal profile recurrent due date

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Here's my scenario , would love it if someone will tell me if it's possible and how to do it :

I have a customer with active profile for a monthly recurring payment , I now decide to give this customer X amount of days free by delaying his payment due date (not by changing his payment amount) , is it possible? (note that X can be any number)

if so then how? (which API? documentation? example? etc.) 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually possible. Once a users signs up for a recurring payment, it's set in stone. You can't change the amount they pay, you can't change the frequency of payments, anything.

You can set up a new profile, and cancel the users recurring payment on the old profile, and tell them to pay on the new profile (which will set up a new recurring payment on a new schedule), but that's about it.

It's not very flexible.

Comment: Thanks for answering , as a matter of fact you can change the amount using the profile editing page , I believe you can increase it by up to 20% every 6 months. FYI

Comment: @RotemSlootzky: Last time I checked, the users had to re-authorize every time you changed anything.

Comment: This is incorrect, at least the amount can be changed, see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/#modify-a-recurring-payments-profile

Comment: @zm0: It was accurate ~6 years ago. Stack really needs an aging policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your due date. I just did by calling them. It takes two billing cycles for it to be changed. They can help forgive you one time if you call and going to be late. So yes you can change your due date

Answer (score 0):

I called to change my billing date.  It takes up to three months and for that period you will be billed on the existing date and the new date.  2 payments will be required.   In these days of computerisation this seems to be ridiculous.  So will leave it until I have a zero balance, and then change the due date.

Comment: You don't think this can be achieved with a Paypal API?